# How would I get a specific line of text in a text file to trigger a JFrame button event

Tags: java, jframe

I was not able to find an example of someone taking a specific line from a text file and using it to trigger a JFrame button event. I would like to use this so when this soundboard opens it will play the same songs as when you closed the program, but ONLY if you didn't stop the songs.

**To be clear I do not want the songs to start up at the spot that it was left off at I would only like the same songs to begin at the beginning.**

The txt document starts off with the four lines as 0's but I would like them to check to see if their 1's to see if it needs to make it run automatically.

Also I am new to the concept of reading and writing files so if I'm doing that in a correct way at all I would greatly appreciate any tips.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class beepBoop extends JFrame {

    JButton Loop1 = new JButton("Play");
    JButton Stop1 = new JButton("Stop");

    URL song1 = beepBoop.class.getResource("song1.wav");
    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(song1);

    public beepBoop() {
        super("AddingSound");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Loop1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /* THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE AND SAVE A SPECIFIC LINE OF A TEXT FILE
             * AS A 1 AND WHEN THIS SPECIFIC LINE OF TEXT IS A 1 WHEN THE PROGRAM BEGINS IT
             * WILL ATTOMATICALLY PLAY THE SONG
             * TO BE CLEAR I DO NOT!!! WANT THE SONG TO PICK UP WHERE IT LEFT OFF I JUST WANT
             * THE SAME SONG TO PLAY FROM THE BEGINNING
             * I WOULD LIKE TO REPEAT THIS PROCESS AT LEAST FOUR TIMES
             */

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.loop();
            }

        });

        Stop1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.stop();
            }

        });

        add(Loop1);
        add(Stop1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new beepBoop();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        File soundstatus = new File("soundstatus.txt");
        try {
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(soundstatus);
            output.println("0");
            output.println("0");
            output.println("0");
            output.println("0");
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
        }

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(soundstatus);
            int sound1 = input.nextInt();
            int sound2 = input.nextInt();
            int sound3 = input.nextInt();
            int sound4 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("sound1: %s sound2: %d\n", sound1, sound2,
                    sound3, sound4);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.printf("Please choose a different file: %s\n", ex);
        }

    }

}
```

A little picture of the project so far. I know I'm an amazing designer aren't I? XD

[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can trigger JFrame events from textual input. But, I think that you can acheive what you want with if/else statements. Also in the future consider providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because people don't have time to read a lot of someone elses code. Maybe that is a reason why you don't have much responses.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use the if else statements to see if the text file has that specific character?

Comment: exactly. But you can't acheive that in one line of code. Sorry but your answer really requires too long answer, and no one here will do the coding for you: here is the process: read file and place the data in object of type string => read that string.

Comment: ... I don't know why I didn't think of that before I've been at this for hours. I feel so dumb now but thank you for the very helpful advice and information you've helped me more in these two comments then like 6 different ppl in 2 other questions i've asked. Thank you for giving me a simple answer instead of telling me im doing it wrong

Comment: What you ask is really the basics, so maybe consider learning it. It will be fun! :)

Comment: I know but I've just started out and I'm just getting my footing and eveyone on here has been so aggressive when I ask things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102202/discussion-between-andrej-and-cosmichero-2025).